# Excel =NOW() displaying date serial number, instead of date/time, in =HYPERLINK to generate email

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook, date-time, hyperlink

I have a `=HYPERLINK()` formula in Excel to generate an email, based on the contents of cells for "To:", "Subject:", and "Body:" fields.

Subject: cell that contains `=NOW()` is properly displaying date/time.

Problem: when the email is generated, it displays date/time as a serial number instead of date/time.

`=HYPERLINK("mailto:" &D6 & "?subject="& D7 & " - " & E7 &"&body=" & D8, "Email")`

*where E7 is =NOW()

Comment: You need to use `TEXT()` to convert that date serial to the date format you want.

Comment: It displays fine -- while in Excel, but becomes a problem only in Outlook. Where do you propose for TEXT() to be used to solve this. @gns100

Comment: wrap your E7, should be something like `text(e7,"mm/dd/yy")` but formatted to how you want and adhering to the excel date format rules

Comment: Can you acknowledge understanding that problem becomes once email is generated in Outlook, not in Excel? Elaborate what you are trying to propose. @gns100

Comment: the REAL problem is that in your `URL()` formula you use the optional friendly name value of "email". This is masking the URL, which you have constructed to use the date serial number. If you used my suggestion, the `Text` formula would convert the date serial to a date format.

Comment: See answer, I confirmed as a solution -- that is a helpful & effective format. @gns100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display the subject correctly in Outlook, you will need to adjust your formula to display the date in the correct format. Your formula will look like this in the end:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:" &D6 & "?subject="& D7 & " - " & TEXT(E7,"DD/MM/YYYY") &"&body=" & D8,"Email")
```

You can also change the display format of the date according to your needs.